# notifications funnel in Firebase Console doesn't marks a message as "Opened" even when the message is delivered and opened

Tags: firebase-notifications

i use Firebase with my android app for testing,
then i'm using Firebase console to send a notification to my phone,
the notification is successfully delivered to my phone but when i open it notifications funnel doesn't marks a message as "Opened" .
what things could cause that??

I include an edited image with big red arrow to make thing more clearly,
thank you.

image:https://i.stack.imgur.com/59zTy.png

Answer (score 1):

I do not even see the sent number (it remains 0)

Answer (score 0):

set the following code in the AppDelegate.m and set  "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled = No" in the Info.plist

```
// With "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled": NO
  - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
          fetchCompletionHandler:
              (void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
  // Let FCM know about the message for analytics etc.
  [[FIRMessaging messaging] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];
  // handle your message.
}
```

Comment: For more details https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/downstream#handle-swizzle

Comment: i have an android phone not an ios one